# Удалились все проекты

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Закрыл проект как надо, выключил комп. Включаю комп вечером - в списке проектов пусто и какой то эррор. Хотя в домашней директории все проекты на месте. В чем может быть дело? среда разработки - `Eclipse`

Comment: попробуй отформатировать диск с проектами

Comment: значит нужно написать, какой именно "эррор", а то телепаты разбрелись по островам.

Comment: эррор "The file does not exist." на счет форматирования - отличный совет, обязательно учту.

Comment: Понятно, будем дальше уточнять. Какого файла не может найти?

Comment: все, которые находятся в папке моего проекта. импортировал проект заного - открываю эклипс мне говорит что не может найти ресурс того класса который был открыл на момент закрытия. и пиктограмма проекта - голубая папочка.

Comment: переходи в правильную среду :) скачай Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте почистить кэш Eclipse. Давно уже не баловался с Eclipse, но по-моему, для чистки кэша надо запустить Eclipse типа так:

```
eclipse -clean
```

Можно и напрямую почистить кэш - погуглите `eclipse+cache+clean`

А вообще переходите на правильную среду, например Intellij IDEA